# how do i include get_absolute_url in my success_url of a class view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-generic-views

How do i include the get_absolute_url defined in the model in the class based view?

models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(default="This is the Body of a Comment.")
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    time_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Post Comments"
        ordering = ["-time_updated"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title + " | " + self.name.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/blogs/post/{self.post.slug}"
```

views.py:

```
class DeleteCommentView(DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = "delete_comment.html"
    success_url = (refer the get_absolute_url)
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect to the page that you already deleted?

Comment: no i deleted the comment on a page and i want to redirect to that page that exists

Comment: @enesislam: the `get_absolute_url` refers to the page of the *post* where the comment is written, but I think this indeed violates the intentions of what `get_absolute_url` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [**`.get_success_url()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeletionMixin):

```
class DeleteCommentView(DeleteView):
    model = Comment
    template_name = 'delete_comment.html'
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()
```

But I think you are here using the `.get_absolute_url()` method the wrong way: see the note below.

---

> **Note**: The [**`get_absolute_url()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) should return a *canonical* URL, that means that for two different model objects the URL should be different and thus point to a view specific for that model object. You thus should not return the same URL for all model objects.